# VBA lookup loop according to lookup count

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am new of VBA programming 
and I am trying to do search look up,
yes I can search single data but if the search count is >1 then I need to 
do a msgbox that will appear based on how many times the string exist

[image]

and I got this result:

[image]

Yes I got the exact result but its only good for the first row of lookup
how about the next row which contains Salary: 234,871 and SSN of 241-652?

I guess I need to loop according to vlookup count but how to do it?

I need to see 2x MsgBox since it has two entries so when I click first msgbox ok
then the other one will follow .. Please help Thanks!

this is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim E_name As String
E_name = InputBox("Enter the Employee Name :")
If Len(E_name) > 0 Then
For i = 1 To 3
  Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Sheets("sample").Range("B3:D8"), 3, False)
  SSN = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Sheets("sample").Range("B3:D8"), 2, False)
  MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Sal & Chr(13) & "SSN is : " & SSN
Next i
Else
  MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")
End If
Exit Sub
MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  MsgBox "Employee Not Present in the table."
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim E_name As String
E_name = InputBox("Enter the Employee Name :")
If Len(E_name) > 0 Then
    lastRow = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = E_name Then
            found = 1
            MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Cells(i, 4) & Chr(13) & "SSN is : " & Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    If found <> 1 Then MsgBox "Employee Not Present in the table."
Else
    MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great!!!

How you done it so fast?
Thanks It works! 

luckily I found VBA expert ...

Comment: by the way can it be done using Range? and not cells?

Comment: Yes. You would use, for example Range("C" & i) instead of Cells(i ,3)

Comment: by the way you are not using vlookup here is the speed differ ? or much more convenient if we use vlookup?

Comment: VLOOKUP just makes it a pain to look for the next occurrence. It's much easier the way I did it. I don't know that the speed will make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim E_name, salary, ssn As String
    Dim row As Integer

    E_name = InputBox("Enter the Employee Name :")

    'Set the start row
    row = 3

    If Len(E_name) > 0 Then

        'Do until the name colum is blank
        Do While Sheets("sample").Range("B" & row) <> ""

            'If name are equal, show message box
            If E_name = Sheets("sample").Range("B" & row) Then

                salary = Sheets("sample").Range("D" & row)

                ssn = Sheets("sample").Range("C" & row)

                MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & salary & Chr(13) & "SSN is : " & ssn

            End If

            'Increase row
            row = row + 1

        Loop

    Else

        MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")

    End If

End Sub
```